# Android setonclicklistener is not working recycler header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app using recycler header. And my recycler having header. The source code recycler header is shown in https://github.com/blipinsk/RecyclerViewHeader.

I want to active the set on click listener in recycler header. when i click the recycler header it shows a toasted message. My code is given below.

I am using in fragment.

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
List<GetDataAdapter> GetDataAdapter1;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;
RecyclerViewHeader recyclerHeader;

String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL;
String JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME = "image_title";
String JSON_IMAGE_URL = "image_url";
String JSON_IMAGE_ID = "id";
String JSON_MRP = "mrp";
String JSON_RATE = "rate";
String JSON_DISCOUNT = "discount";

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;
RequestQueue requestQueue ;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");



    GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = Util.URL_SERVER + "categories.php";

    GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview3);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);

    recyclerHeader = (RecyclerViewHeader) rootView.findViewById(R.id.header);
    recyclerHeader.attachTo(recyclerView);

    recyclerHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("LOG", "clicked");
        }
    });

            JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext(), R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
    progressDialog.show();

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("LOGTAG", "Response :"+response);
                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitleName(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME));
            GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerUrl(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_URL));
            GetDataAdapter2.setImageId(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_ID));
            GetDataAdapter2.setMrp(json.getString(JSON_MRP));

            GetDataAdapter2.setDiscount(json.getString(JSON_DISCOUNT));

            //Log.d("LOGTAG", "JSON_MRP : "+json.getString(JSON_MRP)+"JSON_RATE : "+json.getString(JSON_RATE)+"JSON_DISCOUNT :"+json.getString(JSON_DISCOUNT));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
    }

    recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

static String categoryId;
Context context;
List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter;
ImageLoader imageLoader1;
private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener();
public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){

    super();
    this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.subcategory_items, parent, false);
    v.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);



    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

    GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 =  getDataAdapter.get(position);
    Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());
    Viewholder.Mrp.setText(getDataAdapter1.getMrp());
    Viewholder.Discount.setText(getDataAdapter1.getDiscount());


    categoryId = getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName();
    imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
            ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                    Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
            )
    );

    Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return getDataAdapter.size();
}



class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{



    public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
    public TextView imageid;
    public NetworkImageView networkImageView ;
    public CardView cardView ;

    public TextView Mrp;
    public TextView Rate;
    public TextView Discount;


    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item) ;

        networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1);

        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview1);

        Mrp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMrp) ;
        Rate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRate) ;
        Discount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDiscount) ;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "position : "+pos);
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "position : "+getDataAdapter.get(pos).getImageId());



                ProductFragment fragobj=new ProductFragment();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("subcategory_Product_ID", getDataAdapter.get(pos).getImageId());
                fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
                switchFragment(R.id.container_body, fragobj); //replace container ID




            }
        });


    }
}

public void switchFragment(int id, Fragment fragment) {
    if (context == null)
        return;

    //MainActivity is your activity where FriendsFragment is called
    if (context instanceof HomeActivity) {
        HomeActivity homeActivity = (HomeActivity) context;
        homeActivity.loadFragment(id, fragment);
    }
}

private class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter = new GetDataAdapter();

    }
}
}
```

**fragment_sample.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="@dimen/title_padding"
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/title_padding">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>

<com.bartoszlipinski.recyclerviewheader2.RecyclerViewHeader
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/recycler_divider_width"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_background_header">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="@string/header"
        android:textColor="@color/clouds"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</com.bartoszlipinski.recyclerviewheader2.RecyclerViewHeader>

</FrameLayout>
```

**layout_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/recycler_divider_width"
android:background="@drawable/round_background_green">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:text="@string/item"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/clouds" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout (xml)?

Comment: I have added the xml file. please check it.

Comment: I see you have implemented onClickListener on RecyclerViewHeader but it won't work right?

Comment: Yes, how it possible?

Comment: @john you have a button inside the RecyclerViewHeader, I think you can simple implement onClickListener for this Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting your `OnClickListener` on the `RecyclerViewHeader`, when I believe you want to set it on the button you have inside your `RecyclerViewHeader`.

1. Add an `android:id` to the `Button` in your `RecyclerViewHeader`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="@string/header"
    android:textColor="@color/clouds"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

2. Find this `Button` in your `HomeFragment`

```
recyclerHeader = (RecyclerViewHeader) rootView.findViewById(R.id.header);
recyclerHeader.attachTo(recyclerView);
Button headerButton = (Button) recyclerHeader.findViewById(R.id.button_header);
```

3. Set `OnClickListener` on the `headerButton` instead of the `RecyclerViewHeader`

```
headerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("LOG", "clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: Not getting HeaderButton. Which file should import for HeaderButton.

Comment: I updated the answer (the `2.` point). There is no `HeaderButton`. `headerButton` is an instance of a `Button` which you can keep as a local variable or store as a field.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why `onClickListener` don't work for `RecyclerViewHeader` because inside `RecyclerViewHeader` you have a `Button`.
This button will display above `RecyclerViewHeader` have width/height match `RecyclerViewHeader`.
So you will never be able to click on `RecyclerViewHeader`, just able to click on `Button`

If you still want to handle `onClickListener` on `RecyclerViewHeader`, you need set the size of `Button` smaller then you can click `RecyclerViewHeader`